# TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier in production

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, testflight, udid

In TestFlight's [documentation](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/), it says that settings the device identifier in production will likely cause your application to be rejected.

However, it says nothing about using the advertising id as a replacement. I mean, it seems that apple would only reject it because retrieving the UDID is deprecated in iOS 7.

With that said, would apple care if I track my users in TestFlight using the advertising identifier?

```
// Obsolete in iOS 7 and Apple will reject application...
MonoTouch.TestFlight.TestFlight.SetDeviceIdentifier(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UniqueIdentifier);
// ...but will it reject this?
MonoTouch.TestFlight.TestFlight.SetDeviceIdentifier(ASIdentifierManager.SharedManager.AdvertisingIdentifier.ToString());
MonoTouch.TestFlight.TestFlight.TakeOff(applicationToken);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, UDID access was deprecated in earlier versions of iOS. In iOS 7 UDID access is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDID is deprecated so they only way to track users is using advertising identifier.

That's nothing wrong with that and it will not cause any problems during review.

Comment: I think you meant `UDID` not `UUID`. Not the same thing. Both are represented by hex strings, but have different number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to identify a device/user is to use the UUID method of the NSUUID class to create a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and write its [hex-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation to the user defaults database.

In iOS 6 and later, Apple has done that work for you. Just call [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) method on the [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snipped that you can use with iOS6 and up:

```
#define kApplicationUUIDKey @"kApplicationUUIDKey"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kApplicationUUIDKey];
    if (!UUID) {
        UUID = [[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UUID forKey:kApplicationUUIDKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:UUID];
    [TestFlight takeOff:kTestFlightIdentifierKey];

...

}
```